# selecting current highlighted button with arrow key with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrow-keys

Trying to be able to select the current highlighted button using the right arrow key using javascript.

```
        case hcap.key.Code.RIGHT :
            var select = "button" + index;
            document.getElementById(select).onclick();
            break;
```

thats what i got so far.

Comment: If the first button is selected by default, you should set the index to 0 at the beginning. Then if the user presses the right arrow, do index++ (if he isn't on the last button).

Comment: Are you want to achieve something like this [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/7A97A/1/)?